# plotting multiple pandas series with different length in one chart

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 Panda Series in all with different length, now I want to plot all 10 as box-plots in one chart where x-axis shows the series name.

This would be a standard operation as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) if all series had the same length so that I could make a data frame out of them.

However since this is not the case im not sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The differing length series will not be a problem. Pandas will automatically fill in the missing values with NA.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(100)
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
s3 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(15))

df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2, 's3':s3})

df

0  -1.749765  0.514219 -0.104411
1   0.342680  0.221180 -0.531280
2   1.153036 -1.070043  1.029733
3  -0.252436 -0.189496 -0.438136
4   0.981321  0.255001 -1.118318
5        NaN -0.458027  1.618982
6        NaN  0.435163  1.541605
7        NaN -0.583595 -0.251879
8        NaN  0.816847 -0.842436
9        NaN  0.672721  0.184519
10       NaN       NaN  0.937082
11       NaN       NaN  0.731000
12       NaN       NaN  1.361556
13       NaN       NaN -0.326238
14       NaN       NaN  0.055676

df.plot.box()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have all columns at once, or you are looping, the same can be achieved through `pd.concat` in a loop manner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
s3 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(15))

for i, j in enumerate([s1, s2, s3]):
    df = pd.concat([df, j.rename(str(i))], axis=1)

df
```

Output

```
           0         1         2
0  -1.749765  0.514219 -0.104411
1   0.342680  0.221180 -0.531280
2   1.153036 -1.070043  1.029733
3  -0.252436 -0.189496 -0.438136
4   0.981321  0.255001 -1.118318
5        NaN -0.458027  1.618982
6        NaN  0.435163  1.541605
7        NaN -0.583595 -0.251879
8        NaN  0.816847 -0.842436
9        NaN  0.672721  0.184519
10       NaN       NaN  0.937082
11       NaN       NaN  0.731000
12       NaN       NaN  1.361556
13       NaN       NaN -0.326238
14       NaN       NaN  0.055676
```